# zsh shell autocomplete, how to autocomplete both files and arbitrary strings returned from a function

Tags: linux, shell-script, zsh, kde, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to setup zsh so that it autocompletes my rclone commands, for example `rclone copy gdr <tab>` and it becomes `rclone copy gdrive-johnsmith` while also doing the same thing to file names.

---

rclone did come with a command to generate a zsh autocomplete file, but the file did not autocomplete remote directory names (like `gdrive-johnsmith:` above), just the commands like `copy`, `listremotes`, and `authorize`. I opened up the generated file and could not for the life of me figure out how to make zsh list the remote names (which I can get a list of using `rclone listremotes`) and the files together "the correct way" ([no parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs%20%22no%20parsing%20ls%20:P) :P). Anyways, I ended up giving up and doing just that and now my _rclone file looks something like this:

```
#compdef rclone

_arguments \
    '1: :->level1' \
    '2: :->level2' \
    '3: :($(rclone listremotes) $(ls))'

_arguments '*: :($(rclone listremotes) $(ls))'
```

The entire file is like 38 lines but I don't think there's anything relevant in there (I can post the rest if needed). The "_arguments" line used to look like this:

`_arguments '*: :_files'`

before I changed it to list both the remotes and files in the cwd. Like I said above, I'd like a way to be able to use _files. My current approach is ugly, breaks whenever file or folder names have a space because zsh splits em up, and it groups everything together and it looks horrible:

```
 17:43:06  /usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions
 » rclone copy
_bootctl                   gdrive-fakeName:           _rclone
box-fakeName:              _hostnamectl               _sd_hosts_or_user_at_host
_busctl                    _journalctl                _sd_outputmodes
_curl                      _localectl                 _sd_unit_files
dropbox-google-fakeName:   _loginctl                  _systemctl
```

etc...

Anyways, is there a way to, in zsh:

- A) Use the _files function or anything that doesn't break whenever I press spacebar to autocomplete rclone remote directories?
- B) If A is not possible, is there
  atleast a way to (visually) seperate the normal directories and the
  rclone ones?

ZSH version is 5.1.1, OS is KDE neon 5.11, oh-my-zsh installed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/7cbzl9/multiple_values_for_arguments_action/dprc6wf/):

> You can use _alternative to complete two sorts of things such as
>   directories and rclone remotes. For example, something like:
>
> ```
> _arguments \
>   '3: : _alternative
>     "files:file:_files"
>     "remotes:remote:($(rclone listremotes))"'
> ```
>
> The space before _alternative is important here to avoid _arguments
>   passing compadd options to it.
>
> Whether they are visually separated depends on your style settings. I
>   think oh-my-zsh does this for you but if not, try the following:
>
> ```
> zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
> zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format '%B%d%b'
> ```

Thanks to /u/okapi-a!